# How is $G(x) + G''(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

So in Ivan Niven's proof that $\pi$ is irrational, the function

$$G(x) = f(x) - f^{(2)}(x) + ... -(-1)^nf^{(2n)}(x)$$

is defined. How is $$G(x) + G''(x) = f(x)$$ ?

I figured that every derivative moves two and cancels out except for $f(x)$, but the second derivative of $$-(-1)^nf^{(2n)}(x)$$ will be leftover?

Comment: Is $f$ arbitrary or is it some specific function?

Comment: Just looked this up - $f$ is polynomial of degree $2n$, this is trivial...